# How to call the data from arrays in angular 6

Tags: angular

when I log in that time I am getting the response like below. I want to store the token and id in local storage and cookie. How could I call the data in angular6

```
{
    code: 200
    data:
    {
       alt_email: null
       balance: "100.00"
       current_institution_id: null
       designation: null
       id: 75
       token: "5c5d0d8cb6716"
    }
    status:true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this simply -

```
let a = {
        code: 200,
        data: {
            alt_email: null,
            balance: "100.00",
            current_institution_id: null,
            designation: null,
            id: 75,
            token: "5c5d0d8cb6716",
        },
        status: true
    };

localStorage.setItem('token', a.data.token);
localStorage.setItem('id', a.data.id);
```

PS :  In case of cookies data are always saved in name-value pair using the syntax like `document.cookie`.

For more details read here basic explanation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Answer (score 1):

If your response object is like this

```
 let res =    {
        code: 200
        data: {
        alt_email: null
        balance: "100.00"
        current_institution_id: null
        designation: null
        id: 75
        token: "5c5d0d8cb6716"
        }
        status:true
    }
```

then you can use

```
localStorage.setItem('id', res.data.id);
localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token);
```

and you can retrieve anywhere using

```
localStorage.getItem('id');
localStorage.getItem('token');
```

Comment: Throw error like Property 'data' does not exist on type 'string'

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you get it as a response in the Observable that subscribes to login service, since you mentioned angular 6

```
this.someService.login().subscribe(res => {
  localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token); // <-- add these lines
  localStorage.setItem('id', res.data.id);  // <-- 
});
```

For cookies, use a package or service as described here [How to create cookies in Angular 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50772529/how-to-create-cookies-in-angular-6)

Comment: finally i got it

Comment: Glad I could help @malar

Comment: Do consider an upvote / select answer on solutions that helped.

Comment: I am getting results with compilation error like error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Store[]'.